# Build multiple regression model with Y as a Factor in R

Tags: r, regression, lm

I have a data set that rates customer satisfaction based on three options:

1. Recommend
2. Neutral
3. Not satisfied

I understand those may not be the best options but that's what I have to work with.

Another caveat is that I must build the model in R so I'm trying to determine how to build a multiple regression model when y is a factor.

Once I understand that I want to use a stepwise approach to determine the variables I should use based on the code below:

```
install.packages("MASS")
library("MASS")
model <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, data=DATASET)
step <- stepAIC(model, direction = "both")
summary(step)
```

I don't have any issues when y is numeric, but I don't think I can just arbitrarily assign values to the customer satisfaction by making Recommend == 1, Neutral == 2, and Not Satisfied == 3.

I was thinking about creating three new variables called Recommend, Neutral and Not Satisfied and assigning 1s under columns where the feedback applies to a customer and a 0 when it doesn't.

For example:
Recommend    Neutral    NotSatisfied
1            0          0
0            1          0
0            1          0
1            0          0
0            0          1

If that is an acceptable approach I'm stuck trying to determine how to incorporate all three variables into my model since all of them represent the output I'm trying to predict.

Thank you for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was hoping to understand how to program the model into R so I thought this may be a good first step. I'll check out Cross Validated.

Comment: First decide on a model. Then google will probably tell you how to do that in R. If it doesn’t, then ask here.

Comment: I think you are looking for a logistic regression here. Since there is some order in your dependent variable you could look into ordinal logistic regression

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your dependent variable is an ordered categorical variable.  That is, you know that *Recommend* > *Neutral* > *NotSatisfied*, but you can't treat the variable as interval or numeric.

If this is the case, ordinal regression is recommended.

[The *ordinal* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html) in R makes this relatively easy. There are a few tricks to learn, tho. These models are supported by [the *emmeans* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html).  An analysis of deviance table can be obtained with the *Anova.clm* function in [the *RVAideMemoire* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RVAideMemoire/index.html).  For some worked examples, I recommend looking at a couple of webpages of which I'm the author: [An overview here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_01.html) and [an example here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_11.html).

A different approach is to treat the dependent variable as *unordered* categorical, or nominal.  You might look at the *VGAM*, *mlogit*, and *nnet* packages.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into this and it definitely helped/made more sense.